# Memory not used any more but still allocated

Tags: linux, memory

I have something kind of weird going on with memory.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 servers with Zimbra 8.6 with kernel (for this one) 3.13.0-37-generic. But I have already seen the problem with other kernels.

Memory and swap are full :

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       6112624    5991208     121416         88       4752      79224
-/+ buffers/cache:    5907232     205392
Swap:      3905532    3624768     280764
```

I thought that Zimbra was eating all my memory but, strangely, it doesn't seems like it :

```
# ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | head -n 11
COMMAND         %MEM
java            10.6
clamd            4.7
mysqld           3.0
java             2.0
slapd            1.2
/opt/zimbra/ama  1.1
/opt/zimbra/ama  1.0
/opt/zimbra/ama  1.0
/opt/zimbra/ama  1.0
/opt/zimbra/ama  0.9
```

All my process take like half of the memory. My buffers and cached take nearly nothing.

When I stop Zimbra, there is still 3.5Gb taken:

```
# ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | head -n 12
COMMAND         %MEM
bash             0.0
bash             0.0
bash             0.0
sudo             0.0
rsyslogd         0.0
http             0.0
http             0.0
htop             0.0
init             0.0
ps               0.0
```

After a reboot, less than 200Mb was used.

Server was up for 139 days and memory use was growing bit by bit each day.

My question is then: what could have taken all the memory?

EDIT1, add some infos :

```
$ ls -l /dev/shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 mai    2 12:46 /dev/shm -> /run/shm

$ ipcs 
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    


$ df 
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                 3051744         4    3051740   1% /dev
tmpfs                 611260       496     610764   1% /run
/dev/sda2           14287344   2765996   10772548  21% /
none                       4         0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                    5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none                 3056288         0    3056288   0% /run/shm
none                  102400         0     102400   0% /run/user
```

After reboot, (Zimbra started) :

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       6112576    5712908     399668        832     237892    1829424
-/+ buffers/cache:    3645592    2466984
Swap:      3905532          0    3905532
```

Some graphs of the RAM (I restarted the server around 12:30) :

[image: RAM usage]

Second graph shows results of :

```
ps aux |awk '{s+=$4} END {print s}'
```

And third, results of :

```
smem -tw |grep -v Area | sed 's/ //;s/ //'
```

Comment: Any shared memory (or similar) used? (`ipcs`, `ls -l /dev/shm`, size of tmpfs file systems, ...)

Comment: Could you please provide `free` output in a couple of minutes after the moment when Zimbra is stopped and system is still using a log of memory?

Comment: @Mat, I added some infos.

Comment: @rush, I did not save this info, but my htop was green for 3.5Go.

It's like some process doesn't "unallocate" the memory

Answer (score -1):

Cache.

A good summary at http://www.linuxatemyram.com/.

> Linux is borrowing unused memory for disk caching. This makes it looks
>   like you are low on memory, but you are not! Everything is fine!

To clear the caches use this command, as root, and then observe resulting memory usage.

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: Look at the output of `free` given in the question: it only shows ~80MB in the cache and disk buffers.

Comment: I clear cache (1,2 and 3). So it was not the reason :S

Comment: His free command shows that the user has cached 80 MB memory. Total memory is 6 GB and 5.9 GB real memory is used (without buffers and cache).